# Enable SSL on postgres

Tags: postgresql

i'm trying to force SSL authentication on all remote users in postgresql, however i'm still able to connect without providing any certificates. my expectation is that once force ssl is enabled, no remote user should be allowed to connect with the server without certficates. below is how my `pg_hba.conf` looks like

[image]

and below is `postgresql_conf`

[image]

this is how i'm trying to connect with postgres and it is working

```
psql -h hostnmae -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres --password
```

Comment: Either you didn't reload, or there was an error during reloading (look at the log). Or you are connecting to `localhost`. Please don't post images containing text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ssl only uses server certs, not client certs. (And the server can't force the client to verify the server certs, that is voluntary--if it doesn't, then all you are really getting is Diffie-Hellman-like protection)

Your pg_hba doesn't call for client certs, it calls for md5.

If you want to demand that client certs be used, you need to do tell it that.  Either change the auth method to 'cert', or keep it as 'md5' but add the option 'clientcert=verify-full' to it.

Read [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for the details.

Comment: i've changed method to cert and the server now throws below error while connecting `FATAL:  client certificates can only be checked if a root certificate store is available`, i believe it requires a root.crt file in the data dir which i have already placed in /var/lib/postgresql/12/main

Comment: Your ssl_ca_file is unset.